# Create item without any permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, item-level-permissions, microsoft-flow

Pls help me)

I have a list and when user create an item, flow break inheritance read fields and give different permissions via REST API for this item depending on column value. So different users must see different items.

But it takes 2-10 second, and in this time all users can see all items. 
One of my idea - create item without any permissions, and then flow gave all permissions.

Or maybe u can advice me better way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper column. Set its default value to "new" and hide the column from the form. Filter the views to show only items where the helper column is not equal to "new".

Then let the Flow set the helper column to a different value, e.g. "visible" when it breaks the inheritance.

This way, the new item will not show to users until it has been processed by the Flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is generally a problem of relying upon Flow to perform any kind of "lock down".  You never know how long it will be before the Flow gets triggered.  I have even seen it sometimes take up to 15 minutes before an auto-triggered Flow starts running.

So, if you have the option of starting with the most locked down permissions, then have Flow open it up to more access, or alternatively, you can go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings and set the default for users to only see the items they themselves created, then your Flow can change permissions to open it up to more users as appropriate for your business rules.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What we can confirm is that it is not possible to create item without permissions.

I recommend that you create a new list, which is just to get the user's data.

Then modify your flow to distribute permissions based on the data that the user fills in in this list.

In this case, the user will not see the important information in the original list